# Send data to multiple activites

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I new to android studio and java in general. I am wondering if there is a good way to send data to multiple activities. I have 6 activities in my app right now, on the first activity the user will enter text. I have figured out how to make this text go from the first activity to the second activity. But I also want this text to show up on my 6th activity which is a summary page. Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what studio is this?

Comment: You can always maintain a global static variable and use it across multiple activities in your app.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try SharedPreferences, which saves information into the phone.

From [Android guides](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage):

> If you don't need to store a lot of data and it doesn't require
>   structure, you should use SharedPreferences. The SharedPreferences
>   APIs allow you to read and write persistent key-value pairs of
>   primitive data types: booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings.

You can find more than enough tutorials online. Some of them are:

- [Save Key-Value Data with SharedPreferences - Developer Android](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)
- [Android Shared preferences example - StackoverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example)